# Xpath locator with getText() function doesn't properly catch all text

Tags: xpath

XPath method `contains(text(),.)]` don't return all text properly.

[image: screenshot]

How I can resolve it?

Comment: What did you expect it to find?  The test `contains(text(), .)` will check if the string value of the current element (all its descendant text nodes concatenated together) is a substring of the value of the same element's first text node child, so it will match elements that have a single child which is a text node, and no other children (no child elements, comments, etc.).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I understand. WebDriver's getText() will return all text, right? `driver.findElements(By.xpath("/*[@class='list']/descendant::*"));` And then i will `getText()` in loop